# If $a$ and $b$ are coprime, there exist $n,m\geq 1$ s.t. $a^n+b^m\equiv 1\pmod{ab}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

If $a$ and $b$ are coprime, prove that there exist $n,m\geq 1$ s.t. $$a^n+b^m\equiv 1\pmod{ab}.$$

How can I prove it ? I tried to use the fact that $au+bv=1$ for certain $u,v\in \mathbb Z$, but it's not conclusive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $a$ and $b$ are coprime, then $\gcd(ab,a+b)=1$. Thus, we know with Euler's Theorem:

$$(a+b)^{\varphi(ab)}\equiv 1\mod ab$$

And since all the terms in the expansion of $(a+b)^{\varphi(ab)}$ are divisble by $ab$ except $a^{\varphi(ab)}$ and $b^{\varphi(ab)}$, we know

$$(a+b)^{\varphi(ab)}\equiv a^{\varphi(ab)}+b^{\varphi(ab)} \equiv 1\mod ab$$

so $n=m=\varphi(ab)$ is a solution.

Comment: thank you, but how do you show that $ab$ and $a+b$ are coprime ?

Comment: If $p$ is a prime dividing both $ab$ and $a+b$, then since it divides $ab$, it divides one of $a$ and $b$; and since it divides $a+b$, it must divide the other too. This is a contradiction, since $a$ and $b$ were coprime

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the Chinese remainder theorem. Both congruences

$$a^n+b^m=1 \pmod a ~\text{  and  }~ a^n+b^m=1 \pmod b$$

are simultaneously solvable (Let $m$ be the order of $b$ in $(\mathbb Z/a\mathbb Z)^*$ and the same for $n$ vice versa), hence $a^n+b^m=1 \pmod {ab}$ is solvable by the Chinese remainder theorem.

In contrast to the other (perfectly valid!) answer, this proof also yields a constructive way to obtain the minimal solution for $m,n$.